# Regular Expression for finding JavaScript accessing custom attributes

Tags: regex

I'm fixing our web application to be browser compatible with Internet Explorer 10 (non-compatibility mode) and have run into a couple if issues.  There is a lot of JavaScript that access a custom attribute of an element, which does not work in Internet Explorer 10 (regular mode).  I've fixed most cases by using element.getAttribute("customattribute").  The problem is, there is quite a bit of JavaScript and I do not know all the places that a custom attribute is trying to be obtained.  I've working on finding all occurrences by using a regular expression.  Basically, I want to find anyword, followed by a dot (.) followed by anyword except attributes like id, name, checked, etc, followed by a space or equal sign.  This is what I've come up with so far.

```
    (\w)\.(?!attr|index|all|id|value|className)(\w)([ \t]|=)
```

The words attr, index, all, id, value and className are all being returned though.  Is there a better way (or correct way) to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following modification to obtain the things you are asking for:

```
(\w*)\.(?!attr|index|all|id|value|className|getElementById)(\w*)
```

However there are a lot of dot phrases caught (e.g. "document.getElementById", "xmlhttp.open") which you don't want.  So whitelisting things you do want may be helpful as well:

```
style\.(?!attr|index|all|id|value|className|getElementById)(\w*)
```

Tested at:  http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ with a sample of JavaScript code.  Without more information on the JavaScript code itself there are too many I can suppose to exclude or do the opposite if there are too many custom ones to I want to find.

Comment: when i use the first line you have, it is still finding phrases with "document.all.whatever.value".  The second one only finds phrases such as "document.all("buttons").style.visibility".